# Function is somehow not getting input arguments

Tags: python-2.7

So basicly my project is setup like this:

```
Environment
| -- API
|    | -- Project1
|    |    | -- API_one
|    |         | -- API_one_Project1.py
|    | -- Project2
|    |    | -- API_one
|    |         | -- API_one_Project2.py
|    | API_one.py
| -- External_scripts
|    | -- external_script.py
| framework.py
```

**API_one.py**

```
exec("from API.%s.API_one.API_one_%s import *" % (project, project))
```

If an external scripts wants to use `API_one.py` it just imports it, and `API_one.py` handles which actual implementation is going to be imported based on `project` variable which is injected.

I have a function defined in `API_one_Project1.py` which takes several input arguments, does some work and then returns a value:

**API_one_Project1.py**

```
def foo(argument=None):
    if argument:
        argument += 1
    return argument
```

And when I want to use `foo` from external script and I pass an argument, I never enter `if` statement:

**external_script.py**

```
import API_one as one
one.foo(argument=3)
```

Could anyone explain to me what is going on?

Comment: i'm not sure yet what the problem is but using exec like this seems like a very big flaw in your code. if you want to import a script based on arguments just get the arguments and use if's. as for your problem, did you check your function gets called? if so, with what parameters?

Comment: The problem is when I try to print argument inside foo function i get None and not 3. I didnt want to hardcode script names to that extent. Could you explain whats flawed by using exec?

Comment: can't repro - I tweaked things a bit as I was getting errors and got your expected behaviour - argument was 3. Where are your `API_one.py` and `external_script.py` located relative to `API`, how do you invoke `external_script.py` and from which dir? (is `API` or '.' in your sys.path?)

Comment: I have updated file structure of the whole project how it actually looks like. Every external script is ran through `framework.py`. Since the scripts are ran through `framework.py` actual path to `/Environment` is added to the `sys.path` by python itself.

Comment: Ok please ignore this post, I was not paying attention to a decorator that I had for `foo()` which basicly took all input arguments and converted them to either `int` or `str` based if they are passed as string or a digit: 

`kwargs_ = {k: v.lower() for k, v in kwargs.items() if isinstance(v, str)}

kwargs_ = {k: int(v) if str(v).isdigit() else v for k, v in kwargs.items()}`

I didn't have `else` part in the second filter, that's why I was loosing all input keyword arguments.

Comment: @SirDrinksCoffeeALot it always depends on the program, the script and it's usages but using exec means that if i (as a user) could tweak the variable `project` to be what i want it to be i can run any python script i want on your machine. to solve this it is usually best practice to avoid it \ cleanup the variable `project` before using it